# Javascript password feedbacks

Tags: javascript

So I've been making a password validator that will display feedback on the password a user is making based on the criteria.

HTML:

```
password: <input type="password" id="password" name="password"> <br>

<input type="checkbox" id="passwordReveal">
<label for="passwordReveal">Show Password</label>

<p id="feedback"></p>
```

What I am currently stuck on is how to make all of the error messages display as those criterias are not met, instead of only one error message at a time until all criteria is met.

Comment: do `feedbackElement.innerHTML = ""` first, then use `+=` instead of `=` afterwards.

Comment: might be nicer to make all errors lowercase, then plop the errors into an array, then join them with `and`, then uppercase first char, either with js or CSS .. Password is too short and does not contain a lower case letter.. though generally, you would show just a single error message which tells the user concisely what to enter, i.e *Password must be >= n characters in length and must contain at least one special character, upper and lower case characters*

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like the following where you cummulate the messages in a variable and save the results in the DOM at the end?

```
var feedback = ""
if (password.length < passwordLength) {
  feedback += "Password is too short<br/>";
} else if (!lowerCaseLetters.test(password)) {
  feedback += "Does not contain a lower case letter<br/>";
} else if (!upperCaseLetters.test(password)) {
  feedback += "Does not contain an upper case letter<br/>";
} else if (!numbers.test(password)) {
  feedback += "Does not contain a number<br/>";
} else if (!specials.test(password)) {
  feedback += "Does not contain a special character<br/>";
}
if(feedback.length == 0) {
  feedback = 'password is valid'
}
feedbackElement.innerHTML = feedback;
```

Comment: better if the feedbacks are stored in an array, so that the result feedback array can be easier to be formatted nicely (e.g. wrap it with unordered list)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you show password criteria explicitly and *constantly* show whether they're met, rather than providing feedback *only when it's not* met. See this [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/baadaa/pen/WNEoEoB) as a reference. Also, rather than use `regex.test(string)`, I'd propose `string.match(regex)` here to avoid inaccurate toggling.

```js
// Password criteria
const CRITERIA_LOWERCASE = /[a-z]/g;
const CRITERIA_UPPERCASE = /[A-Z]/g;
const CRITERIA_NUMBERS = /[0-9]/g;
const CRITERIA_SPECIALS = /[^A-z\s\d][\\\^]?/g;
const CRITERIA_LENGTH = 6;

// DOM elements: password feedback
const pwLength = document.querySelector('li.pw-length');
const pwLowercase = document.querySelector('li.pw-lowercase');
const pwUppercase = document.querySelector('li.pw-uppercase');
const pwNumber = document.querySelector('li.pw-number');
const pwSpecial = document.querySelector('li.pw-special');

// DOM elements: inputs
const toggle = document.querySelector('#toggle');
const passwordField = document.querySelector('#password');

toggle.addEventListener('change', () => {
  passwordField.type === 'password' ? passwordField.type = 'text' : passwordField.type = 'password'
})

passwordField.addEventListener('keyup', validatePassword);

function validatePassword() {
  const password = passwordField.value;
  password.length >= CRITERIA_LENGTH ? 
    pwLength.classList.add('pass') : 
    pwLength.classList.remove('pass');
  password.match(CRITERIA_LOWERCASE) ?
    pwLowercase.classList.add('pass') : 
    pwLowercase.classList.remove('pass');
  password.match(CRITERIA_UPPERCASE) ?
    pwUppercase.classList.add('pass') : 
    pwUppercase.classList.remove('pass');
  password.match(CRITERIA_NUMBERS) ?
    pwNumber.classList.add('pass') : 
    pwNumber.classList.remove('pass');
  password.match(CRITERIA_SPECIALS) ?
    pwSpecial.classList.add('pass') : 
    pwSpecial.classList.remove('pass');    
}
```

```css
*, * > * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.passwordBox {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
}
.feedback {
  font-size: small;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.feedback ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}
.feedback li::before {
  content: '';
}
.feedback li.pass::before {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="passwordBox">
    <label for="password">
      Password:
      <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
    </label>
    <label for="toggle">
      Show password
      <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" name="toggle">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="feedback">
    <strong>
      Password requirements
    </strong>
    <ul>
      <li class="pw-length">
        Minimum 6 characters
      </li>
      <li class="pw-lowercase">
        At least 1 lowercase letter
      </li>
      <li class="pw-uppercase">
        At least 1 uppercase letter
      </li>
      <li class="pw-number">
        At least 1 number
      </li>
      <li class="pw-special">
        At least 1 special character
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```